# Getting blank index.html when Angular 7 deploy to github

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have deployed Angular website using Github pages. Entire process is successful but when I am opening the website its showing blank page. Its loading index.html page but still its blank. Can you please help me solve the issue.

Here is the link https://s530860.github.io/website/

https://s530860.github.io/website/

Comment: Did you build it as `ng build --prod` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deploy your website other than the main domain, you need to build it with this type of command.

- In your example I can see you have using sub directory url called `/website`. 
  So run this command.

  ```
    ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /website/
  ```
- When the build is complete, make a copy of docs/index.html and name it docs/404.html.
- Then push your docs directory to Github.

It is clearly mentioned in the official docs.

[Angular Docs - Deploying Github Pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You also need:

```
--deploy-url /website/
```