# Github Pages in Angular gets blank page after second deploy

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

I successfully deployed an angular app to Github Pages with:

```
ng add angular-cli-ghpages
ng deploy --base-href=https://[username].github.io/[repo]/ --name=[username] --email=[email]
```

it worked until I wanted to deploy new changes and used `ng deploy`.

Afterwards the website went blank and repeating the commands above did not change anything. What may be the cause here?

**REPO:** https://github.com/JoseTurron/flight-booking-cdv 
**GH PAGES:** https://joseturron.github.io/flight-booking-cdv/

Comment: The changes you made must have broken it. What changes did you make?

Comment: Some minor changes in the html and component.ts files - rather cosmetic stuff. I don't remember now what that was but I was not changing anything in the package.json etc.

Comment: Is this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55875893/4901118 ?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work for me on the initial deploy without specifying a --base-href but I had to initiate any subsequent deploys by providing --base-href=/my-repo-name/ to get it to work for subsequent deploys.

```
ng deploy --base-href=/my-repo-name/
```